# Hide Column based on another Dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 datasets

```
Dataset1: SystemDisplayName,CustomDisplayName,ColumnName,SourceSystemId 
DataSet2: EscrowDescription,EscrowNumber,EscrowDescriptionAdditional. These are the column names.
```

I need to hide or show the columns in Dataset2 based on the sourcesystemid value in Dataset1
If the sourcesystemid = 18 then the column should be hidden.

```
IIF(LookUp(Fields!Data1.Value,Fields!Data1.Value,Fields!SourceSystemId.Value, "DataSet2") = 18)
```

Comment: Does Dataset1 always return only one row?

Comment: Yes Dataset1 one always returns one row. I am using the uniqueID to pull it up in the query

Comment: What is the issue. If you are using it in your visibility expression you don't need IIF clause. Also replace Dataset2 to Dataset1. `=LookUp(Fields!Data1.Value,Fields!Data1.Value,Fields!SourceSystemId.Value, "DataSet1") = 18`

Comment: Yep I got it. .Value was the problem. Instead I went with the ID